# What is this screw doing on the gas pipe nipple?

Tags: pipe, natural-gas, fitting

What is the screw, on the gas meter nipple, for?   Also, is that nipple black pipe painted grey? or not black pipe?

sorry for out-of-focus image.
[image: my nipples]
[image: more nipples!]

Comment: To connect a pressure gauge for testing purposes - but may depend on location requirements.

Comment: do you mean a pressure test of pipes (with bike pump)  or test the pressure of gas service?

Comment: Two pressure taps is redundant, someone likely put in one wrong nipple. Mine has the tap in the elbow.

Comment: Some testing requires the supply side pressure and the output I know commercial 2 psi systems do and they wack you when you draw more than you are supposed to, kind of like power factor on the electric bill or that’s what I was told many moons ago. In my area residential is 3/4 psi.

Comment: In our area the pressure on the house side of the meter/pressure regulator is 7 inches water column or 1/4 psi. Not sure about the pressure on the supply side of the gas meter, but I think it might be 5 psi or even much greater.